# How to create a CIF using VESTA?

Tags: crystallography, vesta, cif, dft-u, perovskites

I am looking into double perovskite materials. One of the possible materials is $\ce{Cs4CuSb2Cl12}$. Now, although there are a few papers which have done ab intio calculations but none of the common open databases have a CIF for this structure(COD and materials project). The [paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jacs.0c04919) which I am currently looking into has submitted their data to ICSD, but I do not have access.

Due to which I have decided to start working on my own cif file. An older [answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/407/how-can-i-create-a-cif-file-from-x-ray-diffraction-data-in-a-paper-for-compoun) gave a brief description on how to do this using VESTA (and I am also comfortable with the software), but I still have some doubts. Mainly how does one calculate the spatial coordinates of each atoms and how do we add the term U (which I suppose is the energy of some sort)?

If anyone has any idea how I can obtain a CIF or how to go about finding the coordinates and finally making a CIF (please also mention what other information is needed apart from the space group and lattice parameters)

Comment: Why not try contacting the authors? Also it seems the paper has given a good amount of information regarding the bond lengths in the [free supplementary information section](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jacs.0c04919?goto=supporting-info). Also, there is another software called [Avogadro](https://avogadro.cc/) which as I remember can be used to draw the unit cell which can later be optimized using DFT.

Comment: @PBH I have actually contacted the author and hopefully they will be sending me the cif file. But I actually wanted to learn too, thanks for mentioning Avogadro, I will take a look. But the question still remains how to get the coordinates of each respective atom. I have started to study crystallography(in more depth) and stuff like wikcoff positions but  not really sure if I am headed in the correct direction

Comment: ICSD structures can also be obtained from the Cambridge Crystallographic Data Centre (CCDC). The structure in the paper you mentioned is available from [here](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=243918&DatabaseToSearch=Published)

Comment: @ParmeetSinghEP066 was Rashid's last comment helpful?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments or anyone else wants to give an answer.